# Using the select tag in React and working with state to toggle between datasets with React Charts

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, data-visualization

I'm using React Charts. I have a line chart and I'd like to be able to switch between 2 sets of data.
Using the  tag I made a dropdown. Take a look at a live example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/mm2vnz6869

Go to the dropdown and switch to "Revenue". Notice that it switches to the other set of data as desired. But now try to switch back to "Spend". Notice it does not work.
Why is that? Can someone take a look at my logic and let me know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';

let lineData;

const lineDataSpend = {
  labels: ['March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Spend - Account 1',
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: 'green',
      borderColor: 'green',
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointBorderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'green',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 1,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    },
    {
      label: 'Spend - Account 2',
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
      borderColor: 'blue',
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointBorderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'blue',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 1,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      data: [25, 5, 8, 53, 96, 35, 20]
    }
  ]
};

const lineDataRev = {
  labels: ['March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Revenue - Account 1',
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      borderColor: 'red',
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointBorderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'red',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 1,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      data: [27, 9, 37, 31, 102, 42, 19]
    },
    {
      label: 'Revenue - Account 2',
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: 'yellow',
      borderColor: 'yellow',
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointBorderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'yellow',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 1,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      data: [1, 29, 4, 112, 26, 49, 81]
    }
  ]
};

lineData = lineDataSpend; //init the graph data to 'Spend'

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.changeMetric = this.changeMetric.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      selectedMetric: 'Spend'
    };
  }

  changeMetric(event) {

    this.setState({
      selectedMetric: event.target.value
    });

    switch (event.target.value) {
      case 'Spend':
        lineData = lineDataSpend;
        break;
      case 'Revenue':
        lineData = lineDataRev;
        break;
      default:
    }
  }

  render() {
    const lineOptions = {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Account 1 vs Account 2'
      },
      tooltips: {
        enabled: true,
        callbacks: {
          label: function (value, data) {
            console.log('data', data)
            const currentLabel = data.datasets[value.datasetIndex].label;
            return currentLabel + ': ' + '$' + value.yLabel;
          }
        }
      },
      legend: {
        display: true
      },
      maintainAspectRatio: true,
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            callback: function (value) {
              return '$' + parseFloat(value.toFixed(2));
            }
          },
          stacked: false,
          gridLines: {
            display: true,
            color: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)"
          }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
          gridLines: {
            display: false
          }
        }]
      }

    };

    return (
      <div>


        <select onChange={this.changeMetric} value={this.state.selectedMetric}>
          <option value="Spend">Spend</option>
          <option value="Revenue">Revenue</option>
        </select>

        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-xl-10">
            <div className="card">
              <div className="card-header">
                <i className="fa fa-align-justify" />
              </div>
              <div className="card-block">
                <Line data={lineData} options={lineOptions} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    )

  }
}


render(<App />, document.body);
```

In addition to this, Is there a way we could show both graphs at once by using checkbox's? For example, if there are two checkbox's spent, revenue and few other options.If we check spent shows spent data on the graph, if we check both boxes or more it shows all those graphs as such. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lineData initialisation to lineDataSpend is causing the issue. If you directly assign a default object to lineData instead of making it hold the object of lineDataSpend, your problem gets solved.

So, if you change line 103,

```
lineData = lineDataSpend; //init the graph data to 'Spend'
```

to

```
lineData = {
labels: ['March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Spend - Account 1',
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: 'green',
      borderColor: 'green',
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointBorderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'green',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 1,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    },
    {
      label: 'Spend - Account 2',
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
      borderColor: 'blue',
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointBorderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'blue',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 1,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      data: [25, 5, 8, 53, 96, 35, 20]
    }
  ]
}
```

your problem will get solved. You can test the fix here - https://codesandbox.io/s/3rko469pkm

But even I am not clear as to why your initial assignment is causing problem because the assignment looks perfectly fine. Will have to dig deeper to know the reason behind this issue.